# Is this normal urinating?

Tags: urinary-system, urination, gender-specific, urethra

Is it normal for men to have to push, retrieve, push, retrieve at the end of urinating to get the last of it out? It's happens like 6 times or more, and it shoots out lines of pee, and I'm wondering if other guys just end peeing?

Comment: I do this too ;) All you're doing is contracting your pubococcygeus muscle, before you've  finished urinating and you're trapping urine, then you're releasing it upon relaxation. It's not much to worry about. It's only slightly harmful as it may increase your chance of experiencing a UTI (urinary tract infection). I tend to find myself doing it more, when I'm cold. It's root cause is psychological.

Comment: psychological??

Comment: Yes it happens to me sometimes though can't tell what are the conditions for it to happen. When it happens I push as much pee out as I can, and simply stop, knowing I'm not really finished. Usually it works, and the next pee is "normal". :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the mechanism of urinating?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/20859/whats-the-mechanism-of-urinating)